# How to stop a javascript process by another event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

Consider we have a simple cycling Javascript process as:

```
function test() {
    el=document.getElementById("test");
    var opacity = 1;
    var id = setInterval(function() {
    opacity = opacity - 0.1;
    el.style.opacity= opacity;
    \\ if(mouseout) {clearInterval(id);} How to do this?
    if(opacity == 0) {clearInterval(id);}
    }, 500);
}

document.getElementById("test").
addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  test();
});
```

Upon `moveover` event, the process initiates and continues until reaching the `if condition`. How we can define another `if condition` to stop the process by another event.

In the current example, how we can stop the process (reducing the opacity) upon `mouseout` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your `id` variable outside the function. Then you can call `clearInterval(id)` from your `mouseout` handler.

Note that you don't really need the `test()` function, you can put its contents directly in your mouseover handler:

```
var id,
    el = document.getElementById("test");

el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    var opacity = 1;
    id = setInterval(function() {
       opacity = opacity - 0.1;
       el.style.opacity= opacity;
       if(opacity == 0) {clearInterval(id);}
    }, 500);
});
el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
   clearInterval(id);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = document.getElementById("test"),
    opacity = 1,
    id;


el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    id = setInterval(function() {
            opacity = opacity - 0.1;
            el.style.opacity= opacity;
            if(opacity == 0) {clearInterval(id);}
    }, 500);
});

el.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
   clearInterval(id);
});
```